# MikTex 2.9/ TexMaker 4.5 Installing all packages at once?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

so I'm working on a project in TexMaker 4.5 with MikTex 2.9 and, as you might expect, using a bunch of different packages (15+ at the moment). However, I'm working on this on my university's system so every time I recompile I have to install the packages again- in practice this involves running the build command 15+ times so it can install one package every time it builds and discovers it's missing something.

The installation is on a managed PC from the Windows Software Center, so it's a blank slate every time, with no admin rights and limited access to core files.

Is there an easy way for me to just install every necessary package at once, or in one build? Would save me a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: Can you ask your administrator to include the packages you need in the MikTeX installation deployed by the Windows Software Center?

Comment: @Matthias unfortunately not, no

Comment: Let your system install all the packages. Then check their location and copy the whole texmf-tree in some location where it can stay.  Next time you can then attach this tree with `initexmf --register-root=path-to-root-of-the-tree`.

Comment: You can use the portable version of MiKTeX, saved on an usbstick. There you can manage the installed packages by your own. Check the MiKTeX homepage please for the portable version ...  Or you can try to install all missed packages in a localtexmf. Because you have and get no admin right on the university computer you have no other possibilities ...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the responses, will try out the portable version